# Deleting the Gamescene.sks file raises CPU to 25% on device

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I just created a brand new Xcode Game Project. I deleted the `Gamescene.sks` file. Ran it and the cpu instantly to 25-30%. I made another Xcode project just to see if I could replicate it. Ran it before deleting the file and cpu was basically 0%, but sure enough when I deleted the file and ran it again, the cpu jumped up to the same high numbers. My goal is to subclass skscene and use that without the `Gamescene.sks` file. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Some important info missing. Which device / iOS system you are using? What Xcode you are using?  People must have enough info so they can respond appropriately...Also is there any code running or it is a default SpriteKit template project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate this behavior just deleting the .sks file.
The problem is GameViewController is looking for that file at first loading time, as you can see here:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {      <--------------!!
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
```

So you need to initialize it another way. Just as an example, you could init an empty scene like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
          let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000))

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
```

and you'll see 1% of CPU load.